NestJS Warning running end-to-end tests blocking git hooks
I cannot push code to the repository, because git hooks in this project is stuck. So I checked git hooks pre-push script.
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

yarn lint
yarn test
yarn test:e2e

When running end-to-end tests manually of this NestJS application I noticed the following warnings:

Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.


'This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with --detectOpenHandles to troubleshoot this issue.

The test file:
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { AppModule } from './../src/app.module';

describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it('/ (GET)', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/')
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Hello World!');
  });
});

I think some process is opened in background avoiding to tests to finish.

Too general question. No one knows your context.

@SvetoslavPetkov I solved the problem! I also improved the question to help others with same problem

I solved the problem!
In app.e2e-spec.ts app is started in app.init() and never closed:
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });


Closing the connection after the tests solved the problem!
  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });


